# out.print() is not working with jsp method

Tags: java, jsp, methods

`out object` shows error like cannot find symbol. Tried many ways to fix the error. But it stil shows error

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%!
    void loadBuilding() throws Exception {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/crm", "root", "");
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select name from building where 1");
        rs.last();
        int count = rs.getRow();
        if (count > 0) {
            rs.beforeFirst();
            while (rs.next()) {
                out.print("<script>passName('" + rs.getString(1) + "');</script>");
            }
        } else {
            out.print("No Buildings Added Yet");
        }
    }
%>

<%
    loadBuilding();
%>
```

[image: out.print() shows error]

Comment: what is 'out' supposed to be?

Comment: Don't paste code and simply try to work with it. Follow tutorial explaining what is it doing and how.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the methods you are calling on `out`, you might need `out` to be a `PrintWriter` whose output is written to the `OutputStream` of the response generated by this JSP.

Add:

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter (response.getOutputStream ());
```